# Apply functions to pandas groupby and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to understand the Pandas Groupby, but I'm currently seeing some behavior I don't understand. Basically, I have a dataset that looks like (only head shown):

```
 userId movieId rating  timestamp   parsed_time
0   1   2       3.5     1112486027  2005-04-02 23:53:47
1   1   29      3.5     1112484676  2005-04-02 23:31:16
2   1   32      3.5     1112484819  2005-04-02 23:33:39
3   1   47      3.5     1112484727  2005-04-02 23:32:07
4   1   50      3.5     1112484580  2005-04-02 23:29:40
```

I have checked the dataset for NaN/null values, and there are none. Now, I would like to compute the average rating of each movie, as well as the standard deviation.

Getting the average rating is simple:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=',')

average_rating = ratings[['movieId','rating']].groupby('movieId',as_index=False).mean()
average_ratings.rename(columns={'rating':'AverageRating'}, inplace=True)
```

which gives me something like:

```
 movieId    AverageRating
0   1     3.921240
1   2     3.211977
2   3     3.151040
3   4     2.861393
4   5     3.064592
```

So this is all fine and well, and what I expect from the combination of `groupby()` and `mean()`.
Now, I would like to do the same to compute the standard deviation of the movie ratings, and add this as a new column to the `average_rating` df:

```
average_rating['StdDev'] = ratings[['movieId','rating']].groupby('movieId').std()
```

which gives me:

```
    movieId AverageRating   StdDev
0   1       3.921240    NaN
1   2       3.211977    0.889012
2   3       3.151040    0.951150
3   4       2.861393    1.006642
4   5       3.064592    1.095702
```

What puzzles me here, is the NaN that appears as the first entry in my StdDev column. If I extract manually the rows of, say movieId [1,2] and compute the mean and standard deviation just for those:

```
print('Mean movieID 1:')
print(ratings[ratings['movieId']==1]['rating'].mean())
print('StdDev movieID 1:')
print(ratings[ratings['movieId']==1]['rating'].std())
print('Mean movieID:')
print(ratings[ratings['movieId']==2]['rating'].mean())
print('StdDev movieID 2:')
print(ratings[ratings['movieId']==2]['rating'].std())
```

I get returned:

```
Mean movieID 1:
3.921240
StdDev movieID 1:
0.889012
Mean movieID 2:
3.211977
StdDev movieID 2:
0.951150
```

So to me it looks like the `groupby.std()` for some reason skips the first index, replaces that with a NaN, and then fill in the correct values, but shifted by one index. I do not understand this behavior, and it's not what I would expect. Can anyone explain this behavior to me on the second use of groupby, and how to avoid it/get it to do what I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens not during the computation of the standard deviation, but when assigning the result to the new column `StdDev`. The is because pandas does assignment by index, implicitly.

The code below should work because the result of both `groupby` operations is indexed on `movieId`:

```
# note how I remove as_index=False
average_rating = ratings[['movieId','rating']].groupby('movieId').mean()
average_rating['StdDev'] = ratings[['movieId','rating']].groupby('movieId').std()
```

Of course, you should do both in one go:

```
ratings[['movieId','rating']].groupby('movieId').agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

More elegant (or at least more standard):

```
ratings.groupby('movieId')['rating'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution did the job. And I appreciate the more elegant solutions you propose. The double `agg()` is really handy, I wasn't aware that was possible

Comment: A follow-up question; The reason for including the `as_index=False` is that I need to subsequently merge this with a different df, that also has `movieId` as a key, so I want to do a merge on 'movieId'. I attempted to insert an `as_index=False` in your last example, but that is still using the `movieId` as index in the final df (which also puzzles me).

Comment: I agree, it's quite surprising, but `as_index=False` does not work with `agg`. The best solution here would be to finish off with a `.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that in your first groupby, you included `as_index=False`, so the created df has a new serial index. In your secong groupby, you don't include the `as_index` argument, so it uses MovieID as the index.

When you then assign this as a column in `average_ratings` the indexes aren't referring to the same thing.

It just so happens in this case that it *looks like* your index has been shifted, because you have MovieIDs 1-5, and an integer index 0-4. The null value in the StdDev column merely reflects the fact that there isn't a Movie with ID = 0.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thanks for providing the details of the groupby, I knew I was missing something simple!